# Не отображается сообщение в alert

Tags: php, javascript, html, ajax, insert

Есть два файла, в первом находится форма и javascript,во втором код php который пересылает данные с первого файла в БД . Я пытаюсь сделать,чтобы при вводе данных  и нажатии  кнопки отправить выводилось сообщение об успешной отправке,иначе об ошибке,но эти сообщения не выводит,хотя данные в ьд добавляются. Помогите пожалуйста.

Файл 1(html)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Добавление клиента</title>
<script  src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$("document").ready(function() {
$ ("#send").click(function(){
    var dannie = $("form").serialize();
    $.ajax({
        url:'insert.php',
        type: 'POST',
        data: dannie,
        success: function (data) {
            if (data) {
                alert("Успешно добавлена") ;
                      } 
            else {          
            alert("Ошибка");
                 }
                }
});
});
});
</script>
</head>
<body>
<form>
клиент<br/>
<input type="text" name="klient" /><br/>
ОП_форма <br/>
<textarea name="op_forma" ></textarea> <br/> <!-- cols="10" rows="10" -->
<input type="submit"  id="send"  value="Добавить" />
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Файл 2(php)

```
<?php 
$connection=mysql_connect("localhost","reklama","reklama") ;
mysql_select_db('reklama');
mysql_set_charset("SET NAMES utf8");
$ret=true;

mysql_query(" INSERT INTO `klienti` (klient,op_forma)
    VALUES ('". $_POST ['klient'] ."' , '" .  $_POST ['op_forma']  ."')") or $ret=false;
echo $ret;
 ?>
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

У Вас параллельно с ajax'ом идет обычная отправка формы, и страница перезагружается до того, как приходит ответ на ajax. Чтобы не происходил стандартный (не ajax) `submit` формы:

```
$("#send").click(function() {
  var dannie = $("form").serialize();
  $.ajax({
    ...
  });
  return false; // !!!
});
```

Или - по рекомендации @Other :

```
$("#send").click(function(event) {
  event.preventDefault(); // !!!
  var dannie = $("form").serialize();
  $.ajax({
    ...
  });
});
```

A еще:

```
$("form").submit(function(event) {
  event.preventDefault(); // !!!
  var dannie = $("form").serialize();
  $.ajax({
    ...
  });
});
```

Comment: Может лучше `event.preventDefault();`? Может ему всплытие понадобится.